# what the heck is a JPA configuration?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, ant, hibernate-envers

I'm going nuts trying to get a simple [Envers](http://www.jboss.org/files/envers/docs/index.html) example to work. I'm stuck on the `org.hibernate.tool.ant.EnversHibernateToolTask` — it looks like I finally got all the jar files I needed, but now I get the error message

```
[hibernatetool] Persistence unit not found: 'ConsolePU'.

BUILD FAILED
C:\deka\proj\java\test-database\build.xml:61: Persistence unit not found: 'ConsolePU'.
```

As far as I can tell, persistence units are associated with JPA `persistence.xml` files. But I'm not using a persistence.xml file; I'm using hibernate.cfg.xml — but the envers example has a `<jpaconfiguration>` in the ant task:

```
<hibernatetool destdir=".">
        <classpath>
             <fileset dir="src/">
                  <include name="**/*.hbm.xml"/>
            </fileset>

            <path location="${buildDir}" />
        </classpath>
    <jpaconfiguration persistenceunit="ConsolePU" />
    <hbm2ddl
        drop="false"
        create="true"
        export="false"
        outputfilename="versioning-ddl.sql"
        delimiter=";"
        format="true"/>
    </hibernatetool>
```

is there something that I can replace it with to get it to work with the hibernate.cfg.xml file? There seems to be ZERO documentation on how to get all this stuff to work properly.

**edit:** OK, so the main problem was I didn't understand the hibernatetool options and what was appropriate for my app. I did find the [Hibernate ant docs](https://www.redhatrenewals.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Developer_Studio/en/hibernatetools/html/ant.html), fortunately. Thanks. Now I have a new problem: I'm using annotations, but I also have set up a hibernate.cfg.xml for the properties settings. The `hibernatetool` task only lets me run either `<configuration />` or `<annotationconfiguration />` not both, and even `<configuration />` won't work since I already have annotations doing things. How can I migrate my property settings from the hibernate.cfg.xml file to my annotations?

**edit:** Duh, I didn't realize you just do:

```
<annotationconfiguration configurationfile="...filename..." />
```

per the [hibernatetool task docs.](https://www.redhatrenewals.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Developer_Studio/en/hibernatetools/html/ant.html#d0e3018)

Comment: done (I hope)... upvoted but not accepted (nobody's hit the nail on the head yet)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace the `<jpaconfiguration />` with the [`<configuration />`](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/nightly/trunk/en/hibernatetools/html_single/index.html#d0e4247) tag, as detailed in Hibernate Tools docs:

```
<configuration
    configurationfile="hibernate.cfg.xml"
    propertyfile="hibernate.properties"
    entityresolver="EntityResolver classname"
    namingstrategy="NamingStrategy classname">
```

Comment: +1 for finding the docs for hibernate tools -- I wish envers had docs of similar quality :(

Answer (score 5):

Just to give you high level prespective.
JPA is standard persistence API provided by SUN.
You can use any persistence framework like Hibernate,TopLink,JDO etc as persistence provider with JPA.

So just to make things clear

Your code -----> JPA ----->Persistence Provider(Hibernate).

Its will be good practice to use JPA as it is standard library.

So what is your persistence provider information should only be known to JPA and not your code specific XML's.

This is how your persistence.xml will look like

```
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="QuarkFrameworkPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
</persistence-unit>
```

And your Application context will look like (Dependent on JPA , no mention of Hibernate)

```
    <bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
    p:driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" p:url="${db.url}" />




<!-- ADD PERSISTENCE SUPPORT HERE (jpa,etc) -->

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="QuarkFrameworkPU" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

Comment: > You can use any persistence framework like Hibernate,TopLink,JDO etc as persistence provider with JPA.

No you can't. You can use any JPA *implementation*. JDO is a specification for persistence, just like JPA is a specification for persistence.

Comment: hmmm not sure about JDO ..need to check

Answer (score 1):

You need to start at the beginning: [Sun's JPA tutorial](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnbpz.html).

[This](http://www.netbeans.org/kb/articles/hibernate-javaee.html) might help as well.

You need to create the persistence.xml and put it in the META-INF directory for your project.

Hibernate is one concrete implementation for JPA, but there are others (e.g., JDO).

Comment: JDO is a specification for persistence to any type of datastore. It is *not* an implementation of JPA. OpenJPA is an implementation of JPA, as is DataNucleus, or EclipseLink.

Comment: So when Google App Engine tells that they require JPA, and Hibernate or JDO are two of my persistence implementation choices, you're telling me that they have no idea of what they're doing?  Sounds like you're arguing semantics here.

Comment: You said that "there are other" implementations of JPA, and mentioned JDO in that context. So I simply corrected the statement since JDO has no relation to JPA ;-)

Google AppEngine provides support for JDO and JPA, and that support is provided through the DataNucleus implementation of JDO for BigTable, and the DataNucleus implementation of JPA for BigTable. They do not support Hibernate (which is for RDBMS datastore only). Obviously some other group could provide another implementation of JDO or JPA for BigTable datastore if they wanted, the benefit of having specifications for persistence.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the correction.  After viewing your bio, I'm glad to take instruction from an authority on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

You need annotationconfiguration not jpaconfiguration.

Comment: got it. (technically I need either annotationconfiguration or configuration, but in my case I'm using annotations.)

Comment: Right, but annotationconfiguration is your best bet. The envers guys just fixed the issue with making those audit tables' schema when using annotationconfiguration and hibernatetool via ANT.